# RHEL 8.1 - Tiger vnc shows dark screen after connecting

Tags: linux, vnc, remote-desktop

I've followed the instructions shown on the link below to install tigervnc on a Red Hat 8 Enterprise server.

https://www.tecmint.com/install-and-configure-vnc-server-in-centos-7/

However, when I connect to the server from a windows vnc client, I just get a black display with a only a mouse pointer working. This seems to be a fairly common problem, but everything I've googled so far doesn't seem to help / apply.

There is one error message in the log file that could be the problem:

Failed to import environment: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1

Here's the entire log file:

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.9.0 - built Jan 28 2020 09:21:11
Copyright (C) 1999-2018 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12003000, The X.Org Foundation

Thu Mar 26 10:48:35 2020
vncext: VNC extension running!
vncext: Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
vncext: created VNC server for screen 0
Failed to import environment: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1

Thu Mar 26 10:48:38 2020
ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)

Thu Mar 26 11:03:41 2020
Connections: accepted: 192.168.0.17::2372
SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)

Thu Mar 26 11:03:48 2020
VNCSConnST: Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
```

Any thoughts/ideas would be most welcome.

edit: contents of ~/.vnc/xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
# Assume either Gnome will be started by default when installed
# We want to kill the session automatically in this case when user logs out. In case you modify
# /etc/X11/xinit/Xclients or ~/.Xclients yourself to achieve a different result, then you should
# be responsible to modify below code to avoid that your session will be automatically killed
if [ -e /usr/bin/gnome-session ]; then
    vncserver -kill $DISPLAY
fi
```

edit 2:

contents of /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple

# Clean any existing files in /tmp/.X11-unix environment
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver_wrapper <USER> %i
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

contents of /etc/gdm/custom.conf

```
# GDM configuration storage

[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=true
WaylandEnable=false
#TimedLoginEnble=true
#TimedLogin=engineering
#TimedLoginDelay=5

[security]

[xdmcp]


[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
Enable=true
```

Comment: This line `Client needs protocol version 3.8`  in the logs would make me look at your vnc client on windows. is it old or mismatched?  Try another VNC client. I've had good results with UltraVNC.

Comment: @MarkStewart - Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the Ultra VNC windows viewer, but unfotunately got the the same results.